# PHP mail not sending, despite positive response

Tags: php

just came back to a project I'd dropped for a while. I have a simple form on the top of the page (debatecalendar.com) that appears on a button push.

I fill in the form, and I get a success notification, but no email seems to arrive on my end. Not sure how to bug-fix it. Any help appreciated!

The code on the home page is

```
// Init the form once the document is ready
jQuery( init );


// Initialize the form

function init() {

  // Hide the form initially.
  // Make submitForm() the forms submit handler.
  // Position the form so it sits in the centre of the browser window.
  jQuery('#contactForm').hide().submit( submitForm ).addClass( 'positioned' );

  // When the "Send us an email" link is clicked:
  // 1. Fade the content out
  // 2. Display the form
  // 3. Move focus to the first field
  // 4. Prevent the link being followed

  jQuery('a[href="#contactForm"]').click( function() {
    jQuery('#content').fadeTo( 'slow', .2 );
    jQuery('#contactForm').fadeIn( 'slow', function() {
      jQuery('#senderName').focus();
    } )

    return false;
  } );

  // When the "Cancel" button is clicked, close the form
  jQuery('#cancel').click( function() {
    jQuery('#contactForm').fadeOut();
    jQuery('#content').fadeTo( 'slow', 1 );
  } ); 

  // When the "Escape" key is pressed, close the form
  jQuery('#contactForm').keydown( function( event ) {
    if ( event.which == 27 ) {
      jQuery('#contactForm').fadeOut();
      jQuery('#content').fadeTo( 'slow', 1 );
    }
  } );

}



// Submit the form via Ajax

function submitForm() {
  var contactForm = jQuery(this);

  // Are all the fields filled in?

  if ( !jQuery('#senderName').val() || !jQuery('#senderEmail').val() || !jQuery('#message').val() ) {

    // No; display a warning message and return to the form
    jQuery('#incompleteMessage').fadeIn().delay(messageDelay).fadeOut();
    contactForm.fadeOut().delay(messageDelay).fadeIn();

  } else {

    // Yes; submit the form to the PHP script via Ajax

    jQuery('#sendingMessage').fadeIn();
    contactForm.fadeOut();

    jQuery.ajax( {
      url: contactForm.attr( 'action' ) + "?ajax=true",
      type: contactForm.attr( 'method' ),
      data: contactForm.serialize(),
      success: submitFinished
    } );
  }

  // Prevent the default form submission occurring
  return false;
}

// Handle the Ajax response

function submitFinished( response ) {
  response = jQuery.trim( response );
  jQuery('#sendingMessage').fadeOut();

  if ( response == "success" ) {

    // Form submitted successfully:
    // 1. Display the success message
    // 2. Clear the form fields
    // 3. Fade the content back in

    jQuery('#successMessage').fadeIn().delay(messageDelay).fadeOut();
    jQuery('#senderName').val( "" );
    jQuery('#senderEmail').val( "" );
    jQuery('#message').val( "" );

    jQuery('#content').delay(messageDelay+500).fadeTo( 'slow', 1 );

  } else {

    // Form submission failed: Display the failure message,
    // then redisplay the form
    jQuery('#failureMessage').fadeIn().delay(messageDelay).fadeOut();
    jQuery('#contactForm').delay(messageDelay+500).fadeIn();
  }
}
```

and then it's on to the processing of the form, in processForm.php, which reads

```
<?php

// Define some constants
define( "RECIPIENT_NAME", "Debate Calendar" );
define( "RECIPIENT_EMAIL", "events@debatecalendar.com" );
define( "EMAIL_SUBJECT", "Feedback or Add Event" );

// Read the form values
$success = false;
$senderName = isset( $_POST['senderName'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['senderName'] ) : "";
$senderEmail = isset( $_POST['senderEmail'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['senderEmail'] ) : "";
$message = isset( $_POST['message'] ) ? preg_replace( "/(From:|To:|BCC:|CC:|Subject:|Content-Type:)/", "", $_POST['message'] ) : "";

// If all values exist, send the email
if ( $senderName && $senderEmail && $message ) {
  $recipient = RECIPIENT_NAME . " <" . RECIPIENT_EMAIL . ">";
  $headers = "From: " . $senderName . " <" . $senderEmail . ">";
  $success = mail( $recipient, EMAIL_SUBJECT, $message, $headers );
}

// Return an appropriate response to the browser
if ( isset($_GET["ajax"]) ) {
  echo $success ? "success" : "error";
} else {
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Thanks!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php if ( $success ) echo "<p>Thanks for sending your message! We'll get back to you shortly.</p>" ?>
  <?php if ( !$success ) echo "<p>There was a problem sending your message. Please try again.</p>" ?>
  <p>Click your browser's Back button to return to the page.</p>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

All of this code was mashed together from various online examples, 
and any help in clearing up my mess would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked your spam folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows (From http://php.net/mail):

Note:

The Windows implementation of mail() differs in many ways from the Unix implementation. First, it doesn't use a local binary for composing messages but only operates on direct sockets which means a MTA is needed listening on a network socket (which can either on the localhost or a remote machine).

Second, the custom headers like From:, Cc:, Bcc: and Date: are not interpreted by the MTA in the first place, but are parsed by PHP.

As such, the to parameter should not be an address in the form of "Something ". The mail command may not parse this properly while talking with the MTA

Comment: I'm afraid you completely lost me

Answer (score 0):

Okie Dokie! Problem Solved

Found the answer here: 
http://www.therevcounter.com/technology-computing-gadgetry/58477-php-mail-fails-send-domain-email.html

Seems because the email address was the same as the domain, it was trying to handle the email locally. Exact same problem as linked post.

Thanks all